# Django Models Maintain History of Related fields [which user done what and when]

Tags: django, database, django-models

How can I maintain the history of a `Model` as well as its `related_fields` ??

For Eg:

```
====Contact====
| name        |
===============

====ContactPhone======
| contact <ContactID> |
| number              |
=======================
```

I want to maintain revisions of `Contact`, even if the `ContactPhone` changes.

Is there any way? I also want to store which `user` did that change.

P.S. I know https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but it is for only one model.

I'm having a problem with managing related fields for a revision.

Comment: Can a Contact have multiple ContactPhones?

Comment: YES, a contact can have multiple ContactPhones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Custom Solution:

There's an `Application Level` solution, in `REST Serializers`. **Warning:** Use If and only if the `CRUD` is only done using `REST API`, otherwise there'll be a lot of inconsistencies in your system.

### Getting User in Serializers:

In DRF(Django REST Framework), We've Serializers and during `update`, `Create`, or `delete` operations, we can get `user` in serializers (using `context`).

eg:

```
class Ser(serilalizers.Serializer):
    def some_function(self):
       request = self.context.get('request')
       user = request.user
       super(Ser,self).some_function()
```

Using this, we can fetch the user.

### Handling nested changes:

So, Here `Person` is the `Contact` in the question.

```
class PersonSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    links = PersonContactLinkSerializer(many=True)
    phones = PersonContactNumberSerializer(many=True)
    emails = PersonContactEmailSerializer(many=True)
    relation_with = PersonRelationSerializer(many=True)
    workprofile = PersonWorkProfileSerializerPerson(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        updatable_fields = ['suffix', 'prefix', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'marital_status',
                            'religion', 'gender', 'nationality', 'origin_country', 'citizen_of', 'resident_status', 'addresses', 'address_text']
        self.update_actions = []
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            if not field in updatable_fields:
                continue
            new_value = value
            old_value = getattr(instance, field)
            if str(old_value) != str(new_value):
                action = "UPDATE"
                if len(str(new_value)) == 0 or new_value == None:
                    action = "DELETE"
                self.update_actions.append({
                    'action': action,
                    'field': field,
                    'old_value': str(old_value),
                    'new_value': str(new_value),
                    'entity_type': 'PERSON',
                    'entity': "Person ID: <{}>".format(instance.id)
                })
        self.context['update_actions'] = self.update_actions
        person = super(PersonSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        if len(self.update_actions):
            by_user = self.context['request'].user.crm_user
            ContactHistory.save_update_action(
                by_user=by_user, contact=instance.contact, actions=self.update_actions)
        return person
```

and `ContactPhone` is `PersonContactNumber`.

```
class PersonContactNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonContactNumber
        exclude = ('person',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        update_actions = self.context.get('update_actions')
        make_own_history = False
        if update_actions == None:
            update_actions = []
            make_own_history = True

        updatable_fields = ['phone', 'label', 'country_code']
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            if not field in updatable_fields:
                continue
            new_value = value
            old_value = getattr(instance, field)
            if str(old_value) != str(new_value):
                action = "UPDATE"
                if len(str(new_value)) == 0 or new_value == None:
                    action = "DELETE"
                update_actions.append({
                    'action': action,
                    'field': field,
                    'old_value': str(old_value),
                    'new_value': str(new_value),
                    'entity_type': 'PERSON_CONTACT_NUMBER',
                    'entity': "PersonContactNumber Object ID: <{}>".format(instance.id)
                })

        if make_own_history:
            user = self.context['request'].user.crm_user
            ContactHistory.save_update_action(
                by_user=user,
                actions=update_actions,
                contact=instance.person.contact
            )

        return super(PersonContactNumberSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(PersonContactNumberSerializer,
                         self).create(*args, **kwargs)
        update_actions = self.context.get('update_actions')
        make_own_history = False
        if update_actions == None:
            update_actions = []
            make_own_history = True

        updatable_fields = ['phone', 'label', 'country_code']
        for field in updatable_fields:
            new_value = getattr(instance, field)
            old_value = None
            action = "CREATE"
            update_actions.append({
                'action': action,
                'field': field,
                'old_value': str(old_value),
                'new_value': str(new_value),
                'entity_type': 'PERSON_CONTACT_NUMBER',
                'entity': "PersonContactNumber Object ID: <{}>".format(instance.id)
            })

        if make_own_history:
            user = self.context['request'].user.crm_user
            ContactHistory.save_update_action(
                by_user=user,
                actions=update_actions,
                contact=instance.person.contact
            )

        return instance
```

This Creates the history in a nested form, where **parent has control over child's changes**, We're getting **child's** changes in **parent** using `context`.

P.S. You're free to define own `Data Structure` for handling changes, This was my case, I want to save it like that, but,

- you can always define the more specific data structure, where **child's changes** are encapsulated into one `key` and you're controlling them in `parent` after `child's` computation.
- In my case, I'm just accessing the `child`'s changes.

P.S. **You can create a mixin to check redundancy.**

Thank you